# Making a Chrome Extension with React to Look at DOM Changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, google-chrome-extension

I was thinking of using **React** to develop a chrome extension.  This app would need to check for any DOM changes on the current web page the user is on.

I have always used react to check DOM updates **within** the react app itself, is it possible to check the DOM of web pages with a react chrome extension?

**EDIT:** I tried to use Mutation Observer but its not producing any results here.

```
var twitter = document.querySelector('#tweet-box-home-timeline > div'); //twitter time-line specific HTML
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
        console.log(mutation.type); //should log mutation type
        console.log('hello'); // should also log
    });
});

var config = {characterData: true, subtree: true};
observer.observe(twitter, config);
//observer.disconnect();
}
```

**EDIT2:** I got it, thanks!

**New/working code:**

```
$(document).keypress(function() {
  var twitter =  document.querySelector('#tweet-box-home-timeline > div');
  new MutationObserver(function() {
    console.log(twitter.innerHTML);
  }).observe(twitter, {characterData: true,childList: true, subtree: true});
});
}
```

Comment: Use the standard method: MutationObserver in the content script.

Comment: I tried the Mutation Observer, but I am getting no result.  I think i has something to do with it being form input.

Comment: `<input>` elements generate DOM events such as `input` and `change` so you can use a standard event listener. For normal contentEditable div you may also add `childList: true` to your config object.